# Binary Strings without Conditional Logic

Tags: java, string, binary, bit

I am taking a programming course in college, and we are supposed to code a bit string class and a few other classes that extend it. This would be very easy. However, our professor specifically stated we cannot use conditional logic (other than the over ridden `equals()` method).

I cannot ask for code, because that would be cheating. I would really appreciate some insight on how this could be done.

An example method is to convert a `BinaryDigit` enum array into a string of 1's and 0's.

My current way of solving this is:

```
// Loop through array  
{ 
   if (bits[index] == BinaryDigit.ZRO)
        String.append(0)
   else
         String.append(1)
}
```

**Please note**: Please do not send code. I would just like a good example on how to not use conditional logic to solve this. Giving me code would be cheating and I do not cheat on school work.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the `BinaryDigit` enum?

Comment: The BinaryDigit Enum is relatively complete. I would post the actual code, but I fear someone will try and give me an exact answer to my question instead of educating me. That could result in academic misconduct.

Comment: Did the professor mean that you must use `equals` instead of the other *comparison operators* such as `==`, `<`, `>`? Because the `if` is a *conditional statement*, not an compassion operation like the above mentioned (or even `equals`, hiding as a method).

Comment: This is a section of the rubric:5. If-else logic is needed to complete the BitString equals() method. Do not use selection constructs (if-else, switch, conditional) anywhere else in your implementation.

Comment: Can you use a look up, such a HashMap (and can you implement hashCode or compareTo)? The current solution is wrong according to that requirement: "*Do not use ['if'] anywhere else* in your implementation" Also, does the `?:` *conditional operator* count as an 'if'? Can you give the enum the appropriate "0" or "1" values?

Comment: Enums can have values attached to them. If you attach a value, you can get that value when you loop through them. I am trying to be as vague as possible.

Comment: I am aware that it does not match the requirements, It is just to show an example of what I am trying to do in the end. We probably can use any data structure at our disposal. However, this is a freshman course meant to be taken immediately after programming 1. So i doubt that most of the students even know what a hash table is. The only reason I even know what it is, is because I am a senior who forgot to take this course so I am jumping back to a 3000 level course.

Comment: Zeychin.... I think I got the right idea. I am going to test something out using the enum built in ordinal()

Comment: Ordinal is not the recommended way of doing this. It may work, but is considered to be awkward to manage. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html, specifically the Planet enum for an example of what I meant.

Comment: Zeychin post that as the answer and I will mark it. Thanks I figured out how to do that specific method. Now i have like 30 more to go lol

Comment: Hopefully the example method was sufficient to help you think without using conditional operators. Good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example method,
Modify your BinaryDigit enum to use a constructor and to contain some member variable and get that variable when you loop through your list of BinaryDigits.

Check the reference on Java enums here for an example, particularly the Planet enum:
[Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).